# django suit admin filter - simplest way to override lookups

Tags: django, filter, admin

When using Django suit's admin filter, as I select a value, the field name disappears.
For example looking at:
http://djangosuit.com/admin/examples/kitchensink/
[image]

As shown in the image, when someone selects the  "Choices" field, they can only see the value that is selected (Tall).

This can sometimes be bad; for example for a boolean field that is "in stock" you'd only see 'Yes' but I'd prefer to see 'In Stock: Yes'.
I know I can make a custom filter and specify the **lookup tuples**, but I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner more sustainable way to do this.

To illustrate how much redundant code there is:

```
class InventoryFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'is_in_stock'
    parameter_name = 'is_in_stock'
    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (('Yes', 'in stock:Yes'),('No', 'in stock:No'))

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(is_in_stock=True)


@admin.register(Inventory)
class InventoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('is_in_stock',)
    list_filter = ('is_in_stock',)
```

and I have to do this for every variable!
I'm looking for a more intelligent way. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the problem with a custom filter. Is that just too much code?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, extend the template and show the field name before the dropdown (if the field has a value).

Comment: somehow I need to pass the query key to the template. The only way would be using a keyword argument in the constructor but I cannot figure how to to convert the query key into the query. You see, I do not  want to do this for every filter in my admin page because there are hundreds of them.

Comment: Not for every filter, I assume that the template has a forloop ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me , Django-Suit V2

```
list_filter = ('Model_ForeignKey', )
```